# How can I read json from ListenTCP on Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a TCP client which writes JSON strings over a TCP port. I added a ListenTCP processor to read data over socket and write it to file (by PutFile processor).
[image]
But when client write JSON in its side as follow:

```
{
  "id" : "faa4e780-3221-4260-89e6-e46721c4a42a",
  "type" : "Scroll",
  "timestamp" : "2022-04-12 16:45:53",
  "app" : "App-3"
}
{
  "id" : "faa4e780-3221-4260-89e6-e46721c4a42a",
  "type" : "Scroll",
  "timestamp" : "2022-04-12 16:45:53",
  "app" : "App-3"
}
```

the result will split line by line in ListenTCP and each output is a flow file containing a line not the whole JSON message.

How can I detect a Json object over socket in NiFi.

Answer (score 0):

there is a parameter

```
Batching Message Delimiter = \n
```

set it to something else

Comment: I did it before but it's for delimiting batch messages. I need to aggregate messages to detect a json message.

Comment: How nifi could find the end of one message and beginning of another? If you are using new line as a delimiter between messages, then you should not use it inside messages..

Comment: This is my question. I need a processor to detect a json inside opening { and closing }. However, I also use } as delimiter for listenTCP but not work. I think there must be another processor to do that.

Comment: The simplest solution to use some delimiter when you are sending messages for example `\n****\n` instead of new line.